# How to change to a specified branch in Git

Tags: git, github

I cloned Git by running the following command (as root):

```
git clone git://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource.git
```

Then I moved to the version which I want to install by typing:

```
cd virtuoso-opensource
git checkout -t remotes/origin/develop/7
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

However, after installation I found that the installed package is not *develop/7*. The installed package is *develop/6* (I checked using `virtuoso-t -?`). How can I fix this problem?

```
/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db# virtuoso-t -?
```

This is the output which I get:

```
Virtuoso Open Source Edition (multi threaded)
Version 6.1.4.3127-pthreads as of Feb 15 2012
```

Comment: If you do `git branch` from the `virtuoso-opensource` directory, what branch does it say you're on? Do you know for sure that the version of virtuoso in the `develop/7` branch has had its version number incremented? Where does the version number from `virtuoso-t -?` come from?

Comment: Please add what the exact output of `virtuoso-t -?` is. Are you sure you don't have more than one version installed on your machine?

Comment: @Cupcake How do I check whether I have more than 1 version installed on my machine or not. According to me I have only one version installed.

Comment: Version 6.1.4 is [two years old](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commit/d7d6b5f51c69a5541aca20f0b7d667560a25197b), so it's certainly not the version you have built, unless their build system is screwed up (which I don't think). type `where virtuoso -t` to check for existing installations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command that you ran,

```
git checkout -t remotes/origin/develop/7
```

will do exactly what you asked. It will create a local branch `develop/7` based off of and set up to track the remote branch `remotes/origin/develop/7`. I'm not sure why the command `virtuoso-t -?` tells you that the "installed package is `develop/6`".

Comment: I have added the output which I am getting from virtuoso-t -? to the question